Spring boot processing of server.ssl properties
We just upgraded from
<spring.boot.version>2.7.12</spring.boot.version>
<spring.version>5.3.21</spring.version>

to
<spring.boot.version>3.2.3</spring.boot.version>
<spring.version>6.1.6</spring.version>

As stated in the spring boot documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.configure-ssl
We set the following properties
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=shared
server.ssl.key-store=path/to/keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=keystore-password

and you can see them being used by spring boot's embedded Tomcat. See the 'configured from' part.
00:00:42.569 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.certificate     Connector [https-jsse-nio-55556], TLS virtual host [_default_], certificate type [UNDEFINED] configured from [**file:/path/to/keystore.jks**] using alias [**shared**] and with trust store [null]

However, after the upgrade, the keystore is not found; the tomcat tries to use a tomcat default keystore location setting, ~/.keystore, instead of the one we have specified in the properties.
09:50:10.938 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.certificate     Connector [https-jsse-nio-55556], TLS virtual host [_default_], certificate type [UNDEFINED] configured from keystore [**~/.keystore**] using alias [shared] with trust store [null]

There are no explicit references to the above properties in our code base.
That is, we do not inject them anywhere using @Value or refer to them in the code.
So I assume that spring boot is using them.
Questions:
1 - Has something changed so that these properties are no longer visible to the tomcat? Something to do with the ordering of loading of System properties vs Spring properties?
2 - Where are the above properties actually used? I didn't see them in the spring boot source code.


link, 1. ..I'd say it is an "environment issue", ..(of course) best is: you proceed "by priority" (15 -> ... -> 1;)


2... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/server/Ssl.java

Thanks for both of these - priority looks particularly interesting.
As for the SSL class - I can see the setters in there, but the only calls I see are from the tests. Am I wrong to expect to see something like ssl.setKeyStore(Properties.get("server.ssl.key-store")) in the code somewhere? An explicit use of the property?

yes, little wrong, these are "typesafe props"... searching for "getters" is same/more (i-)relevant.. for an "environment issue", you can concentrate your search on 11.-3. (imo), but since "spring boot upgrade", 2. could also be an issue... and 15. is of course very "dangerous"/subtle+strong
